# Why does Windows File Property show Bitrate: 1152 kBit/s for a 48 kHz, 16-bit encoding?

Tags: audio, windows-10, wav

I have a wav file, and every audio editor tells me that this is a 48kHz, 16 bit wav file.

However, when I right-click the wav file and bring up the Windows File Property Dialog, I see "Bit rate: 1152 kBit/s".

Is "Bit rate" not the same a "bits" (for example the "16 bit" that every audio editor tells me)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself:

For WAV files, commonly just named "Bits" means "Bit depth".
For compress files (like ogg or mp3) commonly just named "Bits" means "Bit rate".